# Bigquery can't use alias combined with a flatten table

Tags: google-bigquery

For a strange reason, in Bigquery, I can't use an alias combined with a flatten table

For example the following works:

```
SELECT A.ID FROM Table AS A
```

But the following give: Error: Field 'A.ID' not found.

```
SELECT A.ID FROM FLATTEN(Table, Items) AS A
```

Weirdly the fallowing works

```
SELECT A.ID FROM FLATTEN(Table, Items) AS A
JOIN Table2 as B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

Does anybody has an explanation? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery's legacy SQL often has problems in some cases when table aliases are involved and there is no `JOIN`.  At this point, aliasing issues like this are unlikely to be fixed in legacy SQL. In general, [BigQuery's standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) has better behavior with consistently supporting table and field aliases, so if this behavior bugs you I'd suggest at least taking a look at standard SQL.

Also, you shouldn't need to alias the table in your first or second queries.  The following should work:

```
SELECT ID FROM FLATTEN(Table, Items)
```